# @PostConstruct annotation and spring lifecycle

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

I'm new to Spring, I would like to know:

I have a java class annotated with `@Component` (spring) and inside I have a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. The class is then referenced by `@Autowired` annotated field in another class. Can I assume that the class is only injected after `@PostConstruct` is called?

```
@Component
class AuthenticationMetrics {

    private static final MetricRegistry metrics = new MetricRegistry();

    final Counter requestsTotal;

    final Meter guestLogins;

    final Meter kfUserLogins;

    final Timer guestLoginResponseTime;

    final Timer kfLoginResponseTime;

    @PostConstruct
    public void populateMetricsRegistry() {
        metrics.counter("authentication.requests.totals");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes yuo can assume it... Spring first creates the bean, then checks the eventual @PostConstruct annotation and finally injects the bean. I see, in any case, that you are using a non spring object in the populateMetricsRegistry method. In this case for this object (metrics object) it's your own responsability to manage the correct lifecycle

Comment: I'm confused about the _another class_. Your `AuthenticationMetrics` class will be instantiated, its fields will be injected (none in this sample), then `@PostConstruct` will be called. If you're injecting `AuthenticationMetrics` somewhere, it will be injected before that _somewhere_'s `@PostConstrtuct` is invoked.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you are asking is injection of given class happening after `@PostConstruct` in that bean is called, then the answer is yes - `@PostConstruct` is executed before bean is considered as "injectable"

If you are asking if `@PostConstruct` on given bean is executed after all injections has been done (on the same bean) - then yes - `@PostConstruct` is executed after injections are commited to given bean. This is the reason it exists. Normally you could put `@PostConstruct` actions into the constructor. However, when new object is created (constructor is called) injections are not performed yet - so any initialization that depends on injected objects would fail due to NPE. That is why you need `@PostConstruct`

Comment: Hi, yes I'm asking if @PostConstruct is executed before bean is considered as "injectable", that what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: you can remove this part: "If you are asking if @PostConstruct execution means that bean is injected somewhere - then no." I will accept the answer.

Comment: So does this mean that there is absolutely no use case for @PostConstruct when doing constructor injection?

Answer (score 29):

The handling of annotations such as `@PostConstruct`, `@Resource`, `@PreDestroy` is done via a **BeanPostProcessor**, in this case the [CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). You can see in the following diagram from Spring that these BPP's are handled **after** Dependency Injection but **before** `Bean Ready For Use` (Which means as much as injectable).

[image]

Comment: what will be the next life cycle step after `@PostConstruct`? i want to append user details from `principal` to the `request header` through a custom `interceptor`..please help

Comment: @Kalanka maybe ask a new question for it?  And link back to it here.;. :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Bean creation workflow is:

1. constructior call
2. `@Autowired` fields
3. `@Autowired` setters
4. BeanPostProcessor's `postProcessBeforeInitialization()`, i.e. `@PostConstruct` called by `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`
5. `InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet()`
6. BeanPostProcessor's `postProcessAfterInitialization()`
7. Bean is ready and can be injected to other bean

Comment: You're missing `init()` or other custom initialization method between steps 5 and 6