# @PostContruct giving NullPointerException during server startup

Tags: java, spring, server, javabeans

I am getting *Null Pointer Exception* during server startup in the first line.

```
public class DefaultAreaPostalCodeService extends AbstractBusinessService implements AreaPostalCodeService {

        private Map<String,List<PostalCodeData>> suburbMap;

        @PostConstruct
        @Transactional
        public void initialize() {
            List<AreaPostalCodeModel> postalCodes = areaPostalCodeDao.getAllAreaPostalCodes();
            populateSuburbMap(postalCodes);
        }
    }

<bean id="areaPostalCodeService"
          class="za.co.testro.core.address.impl.DefaultAreaPostalCodeService" parent="abstractBusinessService">
        <property name="areaPostalCodeDao" ref="areaPostalCodeDao" />
    </bean>
```

I simply want to populate the suburbMap at server startup so that I can use it later.

Error logs-

> Error creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>   WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception
>   encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh
>   attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Pinging the JVM took 10 seconds to respond. ERROR
>   [localhost-startStop-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Error initializing
>   global application context!
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.REL

**EDIT 1**:

I am still getting Null Pointer Exception after adding my code to *afterProperties()*.

> INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [ListMergeDirectiveBeanPostProcessor]
>   Post Processing ListMergeDirective
>   [promotionActionResultRaoExtractorListMergeDirective] on Bean
>   [cartRAOProviderExtractors] WARN  [localhost-startStop-1]
>   [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception
>   encoujava.lang.NullPointerException WARN  [localhost-startStop-1]
>   [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context
>   initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService' defined in class path
>   resource [testcore-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException ERROR
>   [localhost-startStop-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Error initializing
>   global application context!
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService' defined in class path
>   resource [testcore-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; ne
>   sted exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]ntered during context
>   initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService' defined in class path
>   resource [testcore-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is

**EDIT 2**:

Still getting Null Pointer Exception after calling the bean with application context.

```
Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("areaPostalCodeDao", AreaPostalCodeDao.class).getAllAreaPostalCodes()
```

Error logs-

> INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [ListMergeDirectiveBeanPostProcessor]
>   Post Processing ListMergeDirective
>   [promotionActionResultRaoExtractorListMergeDirective] on Bean
>   [cartRAOProviderExtractors] WARN  [localhost-startStop-1]
>   [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context
>   initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService' defined in class path
>   resource [testcore-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException WARN 
>   [localhost-startStop-1] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception
>   encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh
>   attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService' defined in class
>   path resource [testcore-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException ERROR
>   [localhost-startStop-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Error initializing
>   global application context!
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService' defined in class path
>   resource [testcore-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; ne
>   sted exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context
>   hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to,
>   Error creating bean with name 'areaPostalCodeService' defined in class
>   path resource [testcore-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:314)

Comment: `BeanCreationException` , post `DefaultAreaPostalCodeService` code

Comment: Try without `@Transactional` annotation. If it works, change your class to a child class of `InitializingBean` and use `@AfterPropertiesSet` annotation instead of `@PostConstruct` as setters injections aren't called in post-construct yet.

Comment: The NPE is likely bubbling up from your initialize method, surround that code with a try catch and see what's up.  You're missing some code here that could be helpful, e.g. the contents of the populateSuburbMap method so this is purely speculation, but are you perhaps trying to add to suburbMap before having constructed it?

Answer (score 1):

it is very normal to have such behavior, because `@PostConstruct` method will be called before injecting `areaPostalCodeDao` bean into `areaPostalCodeDao` property wich is null (for that moment).

There are 4 ways to run some code on bean initializing, but each way succeed in a specific step.
Spring bean setup lifecycle:

1. standard constructor
2. `@PostConstruct`
3. `@Override afterPropertiesSet()` from `InitializingBean` interface
4. `init-method`

So in your case you should do as above :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;  

public class DefaultAreaPostalCodeService extends AbstractBusinessService implements AreaPostalCodeService,InitializingBean {

    private Map<String,List<PostalCodeData>> suburbMap;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        List<AreaPostalCodeModel> postalCodes = areaPostalCodeDao.getAllAreaPostalCodes();
        populateSuburbMap(postalCodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I am still getting the Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: did you try other init-method solution ??

Comment: honestly i have tried everything...ranging from init-method to constructor-arg to @Postconstruct but I am getting Null Pointer Exception everytime and that too in some JVM files. I tried activating my bean after server start-up and that is working perfectly fine. So, I assume there is something wrong with the method I am using to initialize the bean at server startup.

Comment: try this : `ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("areaPostalCodeDao", AreaPostalCodeDao.class).getAllAreaPostalCodes();`

Comment: did you check if `suburbMap` is initialized ??

Comment: I am testing it now. The build and server startup takes a lot of time !!!
Also, I can't access ApplicationContextProvider in my storefront module so I am using Registry.

Comment: Still the same Null Pointer Exception. I have uploaded the logs in original question in EDIT 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174391/discussion-between-mohamed-nabli-and-farrukh-chishti).

Comment: This not true - Beans are already injected at this point.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, maybe not specifically for this case but could help others, is to call the code from the view, call it on first glance. The code would be something like:

In XHTML

```
<f:metadata>
     <f:viewAction action="#{myUI.myVoid()}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that `areaPostalCodeDao` is the cause of the NPE?
I guess, that there is something wrong inside your `initialize()` method.

Please read: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Unlike [Mohamed Nabli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4375543/mohamed-nabli) wrote, Beans are initialised when `@PostConstruct` is called. Simple google research:

- [@PostConstruct annotation and spring lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681142/postconstruct-annotation-and-spring-lifecycle)
- [Baeldung Spring PostConstruct and PreDestroy Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy)